# How to call java script function with asp.net button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm write this code for my page:

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

i want when `asp` button `click` the initialize function,and set the new value for this line:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742--->Load from asp:Text1, -0.120850--->Load from asp:Text2)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call javascript functions from asp button events

```
private void Button_clicked(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code...

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "calljs", "initialize();", true);

    // 'calljs' is just a key, can be anything
    // to pass values 
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "calljs", "initialize(" + val1 + ", " + val2 + ");", true);
    // and modify your js function to allow parameters
}
```

or

if you want to call `initialize();` before the button event fired,

add `onclientclick="initialize();"` attribute to asp button

Comment: what is calljs? how can i send new value to function from asp textbox?

Comment: my friend i want when i fire the button send textbox value to javascript initialize() function.